# IN azure traffic how to implement the following case

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager

In azure traffic manager which is having the following links, how to configure in azure traffic manager for performance based traffic management.

1) http://xxxxx.azure-api.net/application1/service

2) http://xxxxx.azure-api.net/application2/service

I have given the created the azure traffic manager profile with the performance based selection. Then I included the DNS name as **xxxxx.azure-api.net**.

But now how to configure that end user will have one url and azure traffic manager will route the request based on performance or availability of the service.

Comment: are you referring to APP service end point

Comment: no api management endpoint, I'm giving as external endpoint.

Comment: Suggesting you to check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-manage-endpoints#to-add-a-cloud-service-or-an-app-service-endpoint-to-a-traffic-manager-profile

Answer (score 0):

You should add a CNAME to point your company domain to a Traffic manager domain name.

To use a name from your DNS zone, create a CNAME DNS record that maps to the domain name of your Traffic Manager profile. You can find the Traffic Manager domain name in the General section on the Configuration page of the Traffic Manager profile.

For example, to point name www.contoso.com to the Traffic Manager DNS name contoso.trafficmanager.net, you would create the following DNS resource record:

```
www.contoso.com IN CNAME contoso.trafficmanager.net
```

For step by step information, please refer to this [blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2015/02/09/step-by-step-managing-traffic-for-workloads-in-azure/)